# Access related manager method from another manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-managers

I am trying to access a manager method from a manager of a related model but I'm having no success.

Let's say these are my models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    objects = ModelAQuerySet.as_manager()

class ModelB (models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name='a_objs')

    objects = ModelBQuerySet.as_manager()
```

And I am defining the managers as QuerySets, that is:

```
class ModelAQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def description_starts_with(self, desc):
        return self.filter(description__startswith=desc)

class ModelBQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass
```

What I would to do is to create a ModelBQuerySet method that prefetch modelA objects starting with a certain description.

Here's a WRONG example of what I am trying to do:

```
class ModelBQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def prefetch_a_objs_starts_with(self, desc):
        return self.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('a_objs',
                     queryset=ModelAQuerySet.description_starts_with(desc),
                     to_attr='a_objs_with_desc'))
```

This of course doesn't work because `description_starts_with` is an instance method, and here I am invoking it from the class.

Even this is completely wrong I hope it gets the idea of what I'm trying to do.

Question is: how to create a `models.QuerySet` method with a prefetch that can access its related `models.QuerySet` instance methods?

Comment: Why not `ModelA.objects.description_starts_with`?

Comment: because it create circular dependencies error

Comment: @Leonardo: you can import the model in the function itself.

Comment: I know, I wanted to avoid that, there are several ways to fix circular imports and use `queryset=ModelA.objects.description_starts_with(desc)`. I wanted to know if I could do a slightly more elegant solution by calling a manager method from another one.